# What do the double curly braces mean in a PHP MySQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have encountered this PHP/MySQL code, what do the double curly braces do in this statement?

```
$statement = "
            SELECT * FROM
            {{details}}
            WHERE           
            store_id='".......
```

`details` is the name of a table with a prefix (td_details).

Comment: It will probably be replaced later on. See it as a "marker" which will be easier to find in a string (with a function like `str_replace`)

Comment: thanks, I have been searching the entire project in the past day and I have not found any indication of str_replace or some sort of substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Means nothing. Replace {{details}} with your table name.

The author may have just placed them as markers so you know where to change the code as paskl stated in a comment.